# Balls in Bins Problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let there be $n$ bins. Each $i^{th}$ bin contains $n-i$ white balls and $i-1$ black balls. If a bin is picked at random from which two balls are picked without replacement. What would be the probability of the second ball to be white?

Answer (score 2):

If you were to renumber bin $i$, $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$ as bin $n+1-i$--which clearly cannot affect the results--your question would read

> Bin $n+1-i$ contains $n-(n+1-i)=i-1$ white balls and $(n+1-i)-i=n-i$ black balls. ... What would be the probability of the second ball to be white?

Upon exchanging "black" for "white" throughout, *it's exactly the same question as the original.*  Consequently, the probability the second ball is white must equal the probability the second ball is black.  Now apply the [Law of Total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) to obtain the answer.

Comment: Very nice and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

Denote the probability of the event that the second ball is white as $P(white)$. You want to evaluate $P(white)=\sum_{i=1}^nP(white|bin=i)P(bin=i)$. For $P(white|bin=i)$, you want the second ball to be white. There are a total of $n-i+i-1=n-1$ balls in each bin. This is equivalent to either $WW$ or $BW$ being drawn:

$P(white|bin=i)=\frac{n-i}{n-1}\cdot \frac{n-i-1}{n-2}+\frac{i-1}{n-1}\frac{n-i}{n-2}$.

Can you finish it from here?

Comment: I believe you can obtain the same formula, but in a simpler and more insightful form, by observing that the chance the second ball is white must equal the chance the first ball is white, which obviously is $(n-i)/(n-1)$.

Comment: @whuber: I came up with that too *for the first ball*. Bear in mind that this is done **without replacement**. Besides the problem seems to have a rational number as answer. Could there be a way to cancel out these terms?